# compile opencv with cuda for MAC

Tags: macos, opencv, g++, clang

I am trying to compile opencv 2.4.5 with CUDA support in Mac OS X. I am using the cmake gui 2.8.10 with Qt 4.8

After a

```
clang: error: unsupported option '-dumpspecs'
```

in the make i have set the entry CUDA_HOST_COMPILER to /usr/bin/llvm-g++ . But now I receive this error:

```
[ 16%] Built target IlmImf
[ 16%] Building NVCC (Device) object modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_generated_matrix_operations.cu.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wmissing-declarations" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wstrict-prototypes" is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-narrowing"
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor"
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unnamed-type-template-args"
```

What can i do now?

#### SYSTEM SETTINGS

```
OS X 10.8.3 (12D78)
```

and

```
>>> clang --version
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.24) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

and

```
>>> g++ --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
>>> ls -al /usr/bin/g++
/usr/bin/g++ -> llvm-g++-4.2
```

and

```
>>> cc --version
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.24) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
Thread model: posix
>>> ls -al /usr/bin/cc
/usr/bin/cc -> clang
```

Comment: What CMake options "-D" did you use? "-D CUDA_HOST_COMPILER=/usr/bin/llvm-g++" only? try to set CUDA_HOST_COMPILER to your NVCC compiler full path instead of your llvm-g++ full path. Further, check the OpenCV requirements: GCC 4.4.x or later. You used llvm-g++, not GCC.

Comment: i've already tried to use gcc instead of llvm-g++. anyway my gcc is a link: ´/usr/bin/gcc -> llvm-gcc-4.2´ but i think this is the standard way for achieve gcc on mac platform with xcode command line tools.. isn't it?

Comment: anyway, if i use /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.0/bin/nvcc (the path of nvcc) i receive `nvcc fatal   : Unknown option 'dumpspecs'`

Comment: Yes, the XCode command line tools install the GCC in /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 but the minimum required version is 4.4.x (according to Linux installation tutorial of OpenCV), so you should try to compile and install GCC from sources in order to have the newest version. A question: did you try to use the MacPorts? Recently I did a fast setup on a machine with OSX 10.8.3 by using them and it works well.

Comment: i'm using homebre, i tried macports once but i didn't trurly understand how it works..

Comment: With MacPorts you may use: $ sudo port install opencv . The opencv will be available under /opt/local/include/opencv2 . But, according to the portfile: https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/graphics/opencv/Portfile the Nvidia CUDA support should be disabled by default (-DWITH_CUDA=OFF). So, you should set "-DWITH_CUDA=ON" if you need CUDA.

Comment: OpenCV has a long story of issues with CUDA support on OSX. I confirm that in 2.4.5 if you try using g++ you fail because some parameters that are passed to the default /usr/bin/cc compiler of CUDA_HOST_COMPILER are not understood by clang++ (that's linked by /usr/bin/cc). Using clang and setting /usr/bin/gcc for CUDA fails with the unrecognized commands you report (-dumpspecs is not a problem in this case since it is managed by gcc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GCC and G++ to compile. I've used CMake 2.8.11 on OSX Mountain Lion with latest Xcode compilers:

g++ --version returns i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)

Change the CUDA_HOST_COMPILER from /usr/bin/cc to /usr/bin/gcc

Comment: I compiled 2.4.3 with clang and using gcc only as host for CUDA, but apparently something has changed in Apple's clang lately. Perhaps the suggestion of @stoictopia below is a sort of temporary solution until the cmake files are updated.

Comment: Where do I change that variable ? Should I set path ?

Comment: @Sentient07: change it within CMake. It's an Advanced option, that means that, if you use the CMake GUI, you have to click on the "advanced" checkbox to show it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compile the CUDA components using GCC 4.5, while compiling the rest of OpenCV with Clang, otherwise you cannot get the HighGui module to work. HighGui will only compile with the Apple installed compilers because it uses Cocoa. If you do not need HighGui, you can compile OpenCV with GCC. You can specify the proper compilers quite easily with cmake.

I found that the easiest way was to use Homebrew to install cmake and gcc.

I wrote up a detailed gist of how to make it work [here](https://gist.github.com/mlhales/5785725#file-gistfile1-md) that also includes enabling Python support using the Homebrew version.

Answer (score 0):

Disable warning flags in cmake/OpenCVCompilerOptions. Find corresponding warnings and uncomment them using '#'